# Arrow function is undefined when passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

when event handler functions are sent as props to child components. normal functions are being received, but not fat arrow functions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class FruitClass extends Component {
  bananaEvents = {
    color: this.changeColor,
    taste: this.getTaste
  };
  getTaste = () => {
    console.log("sweet");
  };
  changeColor() {
    console.log("Yellow");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Banana {...this.bananaEvents} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Banana(props) {
  console.log("props from FruitClass", props); // {taste: undefined, color: ƒ}
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.color}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

console.log("props from FruitClass", props); // {taste: **undefined**, color: ƒ}

why arrow function, is not received as a function in child component ? how to receive arrow functions as proper functions in child, when sent as props like this?

Comment: I believe it's because you're `spread`ing the props. Remove the `...` and see if the arrow function goes through

Comment: <Banana {this.bananaEvents} /> , gives syntactic error saying "... expected", I want to sent both event handlers ie changeColor, getTaste

Comment: Because it's not an arrow function! You've defined `getTaste = () => {}` but `getColor() {}`, try changing `getColor` to use `getColor = () => {}` instead

Comment: you access getTaste before it is defined. Order matters for props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-arrow functions are still hoisted in classes. If you move bananaEvents after defining the arrow functions your class will work normally.

I tested this just now with

```
class Test {
    vars = { one: this.firstFunction(), two: this.secondFunction() }
    firstFunction() { return 1
    }
    secondFunction = () => 2
}
const test1 = new Test(); // will give an error function undefined
```

and

```
class Test2 {
    firstFunction() { return 1
    }
    secondFunction = () => 2

    vars = { one: this.firstFunction(), two: this.secondFunction() }
}
const test2 = new Test2(); // works normally
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining `getTaste` and `changeColor` differently:

- `getTaste` is defined as a property referencing an arrow function
- `changeColor` is defined as function on the class

Functions live on the prototype of the class, properties live on the instance.

So when the `bananaEvents` property is initialised on an instance of the class, the property `getTaste` does not exist yet, hence `this.getTaste === undefined`.

Define `getTaste` as a function instead of a property:

```
bananaEvents = {
  color: this.changeColor,
  taste: this.getTaste
};
getTaste() {
  console.log("sweet");
};
changeColor() {
  console.log("Yellow");
}
```